# Is it possible to connect to a Google Cloud VM using IPv6?

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, ipv6

I'm trying to SSH into my Google Cloud VM with an IPv6 address. I get `port 22: Connection refused` whenever I try. It works fine if I assign my VM an IPv4 address. It works fine if I SSH using Google's own method through their console. It does not work when I try using my own terminal.

When I mouseover the question mark next to the IPv4 selection, it tells me that not selecting one will mean my VM is inaccessible to the outside internet (pictured.)

[image]

When I mouseover the question mark next to the IPv6 selection, I get a blank box (also pictured.) Is this "Google's way" of telling us we cannot connect to VMs that use IPv6 from the outside internet?

[image]